# 9 kW PWM controller design

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, pwm, high-current, motordriver

I'm designing a 24 V, 350 A, 70 kHz PWM DC brushed motor controller one direction only.

Here is what I came up with until now:
[image: Pwm circuit]

I will use Pi Pico as the microcontroller it can generate 3.3 V PWM with variable duty.

Then signal gets fed in the left to the non inverting input of the LM318 op amp it was choosen becuase it has super high slew rate of 50 V/us so it will not take more than 4 us rise and fall times. I added a reference at the inverting input of 2.5 V. I think it will help suppress noise in the non inverting and make it require much more than just above 0. I will use a single op-amp to feed the whole circuit signal so I don't worry about synchronization, also it provides isolation for the MCU pins.

The signal will be around 12 V square wave it might be a bit less but I only need 10 V at the gate of the MOSFET. The signal will get fed to push pull circuit as a MOSFET driver. (PS, I couldn't find a suitable driver so I have to use this instead.) The push pull uses TIP122 and TIP126 as they can handle up to 5 A and I will need a maximum of 5 A for fast switching, however it wouldn't be a continuous 5 A it will just be short pulses so the average power loss is small and won't require cooling. I also used 2 kilohm to reduce the load on the op amp since it will be driving 20 push pulls and those transistors are Darlington with a gain of at least 1k.

Now we finaly get to the MOSFET it will be an N-chanel MOSFET IRF1404 which is the lowest RDSon I could find at 4 mΩ, I will use 20 in parallel with a shared heatsink to make sure they last long, however I think it isn't really necessary, each one will have around 18 A of current and that translates to 18^2 * 4 mΩ = ~1.3 W of conduction losses for each or 26 W for all of them, each one will have a temp rise of 80°C above ambient so even if I don't use a heat sink they can function in free air conditions. However there are also some switching losses so the heatsink should take care of that without me getting to carried away with the math, I also choose a resistor above the minimum of 2 Ω to prevent gate oscillation and allow good current flow, finally the 1 Ω resistor at the right is similar to load.

This circuit seems OK but I believe I'm missing something. I need decoupling and bypass caps but I'm cautious as I don't want to place a cap that can make the MOSFET turn on more than I need to.

Also I will add NTC to monitor heat and monitor current across all  MOSFETs. I also will be using a regenerative braking using a different group of MOSFETs and a separate signal from the Pi Pico making sure I have some dead time or only allow the circuit to work if all MOSFETs at the main part are off.

I got into details so others can understand if they are attempting to make a similar circuit and also in case I was incorrect with some of my assumptions. I will build this circuit as soon as I feel confident it will work properly, and I will share the results here as well.

Edit: I built the circuit up to the push pull I didn't connect a MOSFET yet here are the results, the inverting input has 2 V from a 5k/1k voltage divider from 12 V source.

1- op amp output at 50% duty, 70 kHz

[image]

2- output of push pull at 50% duty, 70 kHz

[image]

3- push pull at higher duty cycle, 70 kHz seems to work well at higher duty.

[image]

4- push pull at lower duty ~40%, here some issues happen the low starts to rise sooner than expected.

[image]

5- push pull at very low duty ~10%, now it becomes a mess with another pulse coming from nowhere.

[image]

I don't know what causes this weird behavior. I will try a comparator and share the output.

Comment: @All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued *there* (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* || Any improvements to the question decided during the chat, should be made via a question [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comment: *Comments have been moved to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151018/discussion-on-question-by-ahmedh2o-9-kw-pwm-controller-design) and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.*

Comment: thank you I will make sure to move comments to chat if they get big

Answer (score 2):

If you are paralleling MOSFETs you need to think very carefully about how well current will be shared between each device, especially during switching transients.  Unless you get that element right, you will find you will suffer cascading failure as one-by-one the device which switches on first takes all the load and burns out.

There are a number of good app notes on this topic, including [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Parallel_Operation_of_Power_MOSFET_.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b426db703ad9&fileId=db3a30431ed1d7b2011eee77009e547a&ack=t) one and [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PowerMOSFET_Paralleling_power_MOSFET_in_high_current_applications-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462758f5bd101759ca434f111c1&da=t) one from Infineon.

There are also many single piece devices that would be more than capable of taking the full load, and these are likely to be much easier to integrate into a working design.  A quick parametric search of digikey or the like will show these up (253 according to a search I've just made.).

For instance Infineon's [IRL40SC](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRL40SC209/6834098) is good for 478A continuous, and is just $4/piece.

Comment: I don't think a single device would be able to do so 350A is a huge current, if it did exist I would love to know about it, however probably I cant get my hands on it I live in egypt and importing is very hard.

Comment: @AhmedH2O Egypt has no semiconductor fabs so you are importing yours regardless.

Comment: No i buy them from people who import them, I dont want to get in details but you need usd to buy stuff and you can only get from black market and not small amounts, also then you cant use it unless you have foreign currency account which requires a big minimum and a ton of paper work and im still a student i cand do none of this

Comment: Even then it will take 2 monthes for delivery and another 2 for getting reviewed by authority to make sure it isn't going to be used illegaly, and even then you will pay a huge amount of duty maybe 3 times the price or more , so it is totally not worth it, the other importer knows how to deal with this either by bribing or getting a lawyer to pay the fair duty since they never follow the rules

Comment: There are many many parts with the required current handing.  For instance, consider this 478A part at just $4 each.  https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRL40SC209/6834098

Comment: @colintd Wire bond current limit of IRL40SC209 is 300 A, so you would need two of them.

Comment: @Jens you are of course right.  I should have read datasheet more carefully.

Comment: @Jens That's still much easier than having to parallel 20 MOSFETs. When one of the two inevitably switches a little earlier,it won't have much trouble surviving the full load for a few nanoseconds.

Comment: 360 A flowing in a pcb is not trivial. For the first tests I would prefer something with big screws like IXTN600N04T2 and a much lower PWM frequency.

Comment: @AhmedH2O Ask the people who do the import to import good modern semiconductors instead, for example NTMTS0D6N04CLTXG, PSMNR55-40SSHJ or FDMT80040DC.

Comment: it isnt possible to get my hands on it, Im an electronics hobbiest, I dont have a lot of money to import a big amount and the importers wouldnt just buy even 100 of this ic if I asked them, the market is very niche and they sell for college students projects mostly, I base my design on availble parts only.

Comment: Btw im not sure if you are aware or not but the mosfet you mentioned has a max of 300a, but actually at 300a it has 72w !!! Of heat you will still need to parallel a good amount of them, the max current of mosfets isnt a factor you rely much on, you just know that at most it can handle it but with crazy cooling 72 w I dont even know how it could be cooled maybe liquid nitrogen cooling

Comment: Also 20 isnt the minimum it can run fine with 10, but it makes it a bit immune to damage if 2 mosfets fail the mosfet will be passing 20a instead of 18a so really nothing big still 1.6w, I will also make sure the wave is as sharp as possible to make sure switching losses is minimized, even more I will have monitoring over all the parts current and heat, if any part gets more it will be actively removed from the group for x min or seconds